# I dont understand this vector example

Tags: vectors

Why and how is the vector R<sub>PQ</sub> obtained by  R<sub>Q</sub>- R<sub>P</sub> rather than R <sub>P</sub> - R<sub>Q</sub> if the P is written before the Q?

[Vector Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNSLu.png)

Comment: What is the definition of $R_{PQ}$?

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the vector is from $P$ to $Q$, which is why the $P$ is written before the $Q$. $R_P - R_Q$ would have the same magnitude, but point in the opposite direction.

**Edit:** You can just as easily write the vector as $-R_P + R_Q$, where the $P$ is written first. $-R_P + R_Q$ is the same as $R_Q-R_P$.